# "Monotonically increasing integers" exact definition

Tags: definition

If nothing else is specified, does the term "monotonically increasing integers" mean that $$f(k+1)+1 = f(k), \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$$ 
or

$$f(k+1) \geq f(k), \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: It means a sequence of integers that is increasing.

Comment: The second is true I believe. If it is by an integer amount each time it should be of the form: $$f(k+1)=f(k)+c$$

Comment: The phrase "monotonically increasing integers" in isolation is pretty much meaningless.  What is the full context in which it appears?

Comment: Assuming you mean "a monotonically increasing sequence of integers," it's a little ambiguous between $f(k+1) \ge f(k)$ ("nondecreasing") and $f(k+1) > f(k)$ ("strictly increasing").